# FactoryGirl - NoMethodError when calling def_delegators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm using FactoryGirl and Rspec for testing on rails, and I have come across a problem when I use methods that are define using `def_delegators`.

For example this test:

```
it 'has the weekly discount' do
  //I also tried using create here
  menu = FactoryGirl.build(:menu, weekly_price: 100, price: 200)
  meal = FactoryGirl.build(:meal, menu: menu)
  price = meal.price
end
```

Fails on the last line with this error:

```
1) Order has the weekly discount
   Failure/Error: price = meal.price

   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass
   # ./spec/models/order_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

And this is how price is defined in `Meal`:

```
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
  extend Forwardable
  belongs_to :menu

  def_delegators :@menu, :price
end
```

If I change it to this:

```
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
  extend Forwardable
  belongs_to :menu

  def price
    menu.price
  end
end
```

The test passes. I use def_delegators in other places and in all the tests have been failing with the same `NoMethodError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code

```
def_delegators :@menu, :price
```

And this code

```
def price
  menu.price
end
```

they do different things. Delegate to the method, not the (non-existing) instance variable

```
def_delegators :menu, :price
```

Comment: That was it, but I was following this doc http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html when should I use that?

Comment: @moondaisy: when should you use what, delegation to instance variable? When you have an instance variable without a reader. Me, I prefer to use readers whenever possible.